# Is it true that the functor of completion of a module over a local ring is injective on isomorphism classes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, local-rings

Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring and $\hat A$ be its completion. Then we have the functor of completion from the category of finitely generated $A$-modules to the category of finitely generated $\hat A$-modules.
$${\sf mod}(A) \to {\sf mod}(\hat A)$$
$$M\mapsto \hat M $$
**Question:** Is it true that the functor is injective on isomorphism classes?

**Remark:** The homomorphism $A\to \hat A$ is faithfully flat. Then $\hat AI\cap A=I$ for any ideal $I$ of $A$. Using this one can check that the functor is injective on isomorphism classes of cyclic modules.

Comment: Yes. This is true more generally if you replace $\widehat{A}$ by any noetherian (commutative) ring faithfully flat over $A$: see EGA IV.2, Proposition 2.5.8 (taking $B=A$
 in that Proposition).